# What is the formal definition of game, as used in game theory?

Tags: definition, game-theory

I am very much interested in a formal, rigorous definition of game, as used in the mathematical discipline of game theory. Now, I know that the philosopher Wittgenstein said that some words, like the word "game", can't be given an adequate definition, merely a family resemblance. However, I am still interested in such a formal definition, if one exists. Has anyone formally defined a game in a mathematical way, in some book or paper?

Comment: Yes, it's in the Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_theory#Representation_of_games

Comment: See also [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Cooperative_game)